# Facebook - Permissions Dialog on IE7

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

This works well in Chrome/Safari/Firefox etc. But I can't get it working in IE7. Any ideas?

I have a cross-domain channel set up, and that seems to be working elsewhere.

I bring up a permissions dialog like this:

```
o.method = 'permissions.request';
o.perms = 'email';
o.display = 'dialog';

FB.ui(o, function(res) {
   // do something
});
```

In IE this appears as a popup, but after granting the permission, the popup does not close - and redirects to my cross-domain channel url.

Any ideas how to automatically close the dialog?

A second problem is if I manually close the dialog, the callback is invoked, but without the granted permission. Could be related to the first point, but I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't rule out the possibility of a bug on facebook's end.  Also: are there any JS errors being raised?

Comment: Turns out this only happens without Flash installed.

Comment: Do you invoke this directly in your canvas? Or maybe from additional iframe in your canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a suspicion that `permissions.request` is a deprecated method. The correct way to ask the user for permissions now is the [`FB.login()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) method.

For example:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
   // logged in
  } else {
    // user cancelled login or did not fully authorize
  }
}, {scope: 'email'});
```

Comment: Thanks! It was a long while ago (and another company ago) that I asked this. Did you test this out? I'll accept it if you did.

Comment: Its basically just a copy and paste from the `FB.login()` documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/